# How do i use a loop in maxima to plot multiple vectors?

Tags: loops, math, vector, maxima

I am trying to plot some vectors of the form [x,-y] for any point (x,y) so I tried this:

```
for i:1 while i<=21 do 
    (for j:1 while j<=21 do
      (draw2d(
        xrange=[0,50],
        yrange=[0,50],
        vector([i,j],[i,-j])
        )
       ));
```

But the gnuplot window is gets refreshed on each iteration so I tried to put the two loops after draw2d and right before "vector" but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`draw2d` (likewise `draw3d`) draws a whole "scene" which is described by its arguments. Everything in the arguments is one "scene". So to create a scene with different things in it, you want to make a list that has all the things you want, and then apply `draw2d` to it, i.e., tell Maxima to call `draw2d` with that list of arguments.

Here's an example to illustrate that. I'll create a list of all the vectors first. The `vector` graphic object takes some options, such as `head_type` and so on. I'll make a list with the options I want, and then append the options and the vectors list to get all the arguments I want. Finally I'll call `draw2d` to display the scene.

```
(%i2) load (draw) $
(%i3) myvectors: makelist (makelist (vector([i, j], [i, -j]), j, 1, 5), i, 1, 5);
(%o3) [[vector([1, 1], [1, - 1]), vector([1, 2], [1, - 2]), 
vector([1, 3], [1, - 3]), vector([1, 4], [1, - 4]), 
vector([1, 5], [1, - 5])], [vector([2, 1], [2, - 1]), 
vector([2, 2], [2, - 2]), vector([2, 3], [2, - 3]), 
vector([2, 4], [2, - 4]), vector([2, 5], [2, - 5])], 
[vector([3, 1], [3, - 1]), vector([3, 2], [3, - 2]), 
vector([3, 3], [3, - 3]), vector([3, 4], [3, - 4]), 
vector([3, 5], [3, - 5])], [vector([4, 1], [4, - 1]), 
vector([4, 2], [4, - 2]), vector([4, 3], [4, - 3]), 
vector([4, 4], [4, - 4]), vector([4, 5], [4, - 5])], 
[vector([5, 1], [5, - 1]), vector([5, 2], [5, - 2]), 
vector([5, 3], [5, - 3]), vector([5, 4], [5, - 4]), 
vector([5, 5], [5, - 5])]]
(%i4) vector_options: [head_length = 0.2, head_angle = 15, head_type = empty];
(%o4) [head_length = 0.2, head_angle = 15, head_type = empty]
(%i5) append (vector_options, myvectors);
(%o5) [head_length = 0.2, head_angle = 15, head_type = empty, 
[vector([1, 1], [1, - 1]), vector([1, 2], [1, - 2]), 
vector([1, 3], [1, - 3]), vector([1, 4], [1, - 4]), 
vector([1, 5], [1, - 5])], [vector([2, 1], [2, - 1]), 
vector([2, 2], [2, - 2]), vector([2, 3], [2, - 3]), 
vector([2, 4], [2, - 4]), vector([2, 5], [2, - 5])], 
[vector([3, 1], [3, - 1]), vector([3, 2], [3, - 2]), 
vector([3, 3], [3, - 3]), vector([3, 4], [3, - 4]), 
vector([3, 5], [3, - 5])], [vector([4, 1], [4, - 1]), 
vector([4, 2], [4, - 2]), vector([4, 3], [4, - 3]), 
vector([4, 4], [4, - 4]), vector([4, 5], [4, - 5])], 
[vector([5, 1], [5, - 1]), vector([5, 2], [5, - 2]), 
vector([5, 3], [5, - 3]), vector([5, 4], [5, - 4]), 
vector([5, 5], [5, - 5])]]
(%i6) apply (draw2d, %);
```

Of course, you can redo the example with the number of vectors equal to 21^2 instead of 5^2, and you can change the options as you want. You can also create other graphic objects and append them to the arguments list and then apply `draw2d` to all the arguments.

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:N-th_arm_stars.svg  here is the example image with code